# How can I generate combining characters on windows?

Tags: windows, text-editors, unicode, diacritics

A while ago [I asked this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24796350/why-are-some-characters-like-overlapped) where I found out about combining characters and how for `alt+777` you get `○` on most editors and  `̉`  on skype, which can be combined with a previous character and eventually generate a word like this: `mủt̉ả̉̉̉t̉ẻd̉W̉ỏ̉r̉̉d̉̉`

Today, I want to generate it again, but I don't have skype on this machine (running windows) and I don't want to install it just so that I can combine a character with that diacritic.

How can I generate *Unicode codepoint 777* so that it combines with the previous character, instead of just rendering ○, on windows?

Comment: We also have [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) where your original question would *probably* fit in. Just informing, in case you don't get help here.